# Could not open the modal pop up with each time click using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I need to open the modal pop up while user will click on button using Angular.js but its opening first time click and when closed the modal clicked again to open its not opening. Overall this pop up is opening each two times click on button interval.

Check my following code what I have tried so far.

```
<td>
  <a ui-sref='app.ownerinfo.owner.vew'>
    <input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green'
           value='Edit' ng-click="editOwnerData(usr.owner_id);">
  </a>
</td>

<modal title="Owner Information" visible="showModalOwner">
    <p>MOdal Window</p>
</modal>
```

```
$scope.editOwnerData=function(owner_id){
    $scope.showModalOwner = !$scope.showModalOwner;
}
```

```
dashboard.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:false,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Here I need for each time button click the pop up should open where now its opening after clicking 2 times.